# PNG images render incorrectly in running iOS app

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, png

I have two pencil sketch PNGs which I'm rendering within UIImageViews in an iOS app.

The images on the **left** render **correctly**—the strokes are thick. This is how they appear in Figma, on my computer, and in Xcode (storyboard).

The images on the **right** render **incorrectly**—the strokes are very thin. This is how they appear when the app actually runs (screenshots).

Why/how could these images be rendering differently in Xcode & Figma vs the actual app?

[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 1]

For reference, here are the original PNGs:

[[Squiggly]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89CJn.png)
[[Two people]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpL4c.png)

Comment: This is your "Two people" image ... on white, lightGray, darkGray, black, red, green, blue and yellow backgrounds. What are you expecting? https://i.stack.imgur.com/077Xv.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem has something to do with Xcode 15 beta and iOS 17 beta.

I ran the app on the iOS 16 simulator from Xcode 14 and it rendered correctly.

[image]

Xcode 15 beta, iOS 17 (left). Xcode 14, iOS 16 (right)

I created an issue on [Apple Developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735896).

Answer (score 0):

They both have an alpha channel. Their appearances are likely due to differences in the backgrounds that the PNG images are placed over.